# Mixed Hodge Structure on the first cohomology of surfaces.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

I want to know whether any of the following questions are true or not. If they are not true I will appreciate a counter-example:

1. If $X$ is a smooth complex non-simply connected projective surface, with a normal crossing divisor $D$ on $X$ then $H^1(X, \mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H^1(X-D, \mathbb{Q})$ is an isomorphism.
2. The mixed Hodge structure on the first rational cohomology of smooth complex quasi-projective surfaces is always pure.

Comment: The two statement will be equivalent if "pure" in the second statement is replaced by "pure of weight one".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on numbers of irreducible components of $D$ as well as the relations of their fundamental classes in $H^2(X)$.

Assume that $X$ is smooth projective, and $D$ is a normal crossing divisor. There is an exact sequence
$$H^1(X,X-D,\mathbb Q)\to H^1(X,\mathbb Q)\xrightarrow{f} H^1(X-D,\mathbb Q)\to H^2(X,X-D,\mathbb Q)\xrightarrow{g} H^2(X,\mathbb Q)$$

So to determine if $f$ is isomorphism, we need to compute $H^i(X,X-D,\mathbb Q)$, $i=1,2$ first.

When $D$ is smooth, or it has only one component, Thom isomorphism implies that $H^i(X,X-D)$$\cong H^{i-2}(D)$, which is $\mathbb Q$ when $i=2$ and $0$ when $i=1$. The Gysin homomorphism $g$ sends a generator to the fundamental class of $D$, which is not trivial, so $f$ is an isomorphism.

In general, by Fujiki's paper D*uality of Mixed Hodge Structures of Algebraic Varieties*, there is a duality between mixed Hodge structures

$$H^{2n-i}(D,\mathbb Q)\times H^i(X,X-D,\mathbb Q)\to \mathbb Q.$$

Set $i=1,2$, we find $h^1(X,X-D,\mathbb Q)=0$ and $h^2(X,X-D,\mathbb Q)=h^2(D,\mathbb Q)=k$, where $k$ is the number of irreducible components of $D$. The exact sequence becomes

$$0\to H^1(X,\mathbb Q)\xrightarrow{f} H^1(X-D,\mathbb Q)\to \mathbb Q^k\xrightarrow{g} H^2(X,\mathbb Q).$$

$g$ sends each component $D_i$ of $D$ to its fundamental class. So the conclusion is

**Claim:** *$H^1(X,\mathbb Q)\to H^1(X-D,\mathbb Q)$ is an isomorphism if and only if the mixed Hodge structure $H^1(X-D,\mathbb Q)$ is pure of weight one if and only if the fundamental classes $[D_i]$ of each component of $D$ are linearly independent in $H^2(X,\mathbb Q)$.*

For example, when $X=\mathbb P^2$, $D=L_1\cup L_2$ is union of two lines, the relation $[L_1]=[L_2]$ tells us that the mixed Hodge structure on $H^1(\mathbb P^2\setminus (L_1\cap L_2))$ is concentrated on weight two (and pure).

When $X=Bl_p\mathbb P^2$ is blowup of one point on $\mathbb P^2$ and $D=L\cup E$, where $D$ is the strict transform of a line through $p$, and $E$ is the exceptional divisor, the MHS on  $H^1(X\setminus D)$ is pure.

To give an example where $H^1(X\setminus D)$ is not pure, just take any $X=\mathbb P^1\times C$ where $C$ is a curve with genus $g\ge 1$. Take $D$ to be the union of two disjoint fibers of $X\to \mathbb P^1$, then $W_1H^1(X\setminus D)=H^1(X)=\mathbb Q^{2g}$ and $W_2/W_1\cong \mathbb Q$, $H^1(X\setminus D)$ is not pure.

Comment: Did you anywhere use being a surface? Is the second statement true for higher dimensional varieties?

Comment: You just need $D$ to be codimension one. $X$ can have any dimension.

Comment: So your conclusion is that in general for smooth projective $X$ and a normal crossing divisor $D$ $H^1(X, \mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H^1(X-D, \mathbb{Q})$ is an isomorphism? This is incorrect. The simplest example is $X=\mathbb{P}^2$ and $D$ to be two general hyperplanes meaning two intersecting $\mathbb{P}^1$. Then $H^1(X)=0$ but $X-D= \mathbb{R}^4-\mathbb{R}^2$ which deformation retracts onto a plane minus a point and has a non-trivial $H^1$.

Comment: I made a mistake in the computation. The new conclusion is of the above.

Comment: $H^1(\mathbb{P}^2\setminus (L_1\cap L_2))$ has to be pure, because rationally it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ so it is rank one. Any rank one cohomology can only be pure. Impurity automatically implies at least rank $2$. So still this does not answer the question asked. (Does not provide counter example to the any of the two statements)

Comment: replace $\mathbb P^2$ by any surface with nontrivial $H^1$ is enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137701/discussion-between-user127776-and-ag-learner).